# Nested Scheme Functions Not Returning Properly

Tags: scheme

I have created a function that can determine if a character is in a list. While it works fine by itself, it does not work properly when called by another function which is suppose to compare the elements of a list to several key words. I have also tried using the functions memq, memv, and member, but they fail as well. I would like to know what it is that is causing my program to not return #t and where I went wrong.

```
(define in?
  (lambda (y xs)
    (if (memq y xs) #t #f)))

(define det?
  (lambda (xs)
    (if (in? 'a xs) #t)
    (if (in? 'an xs) #t)
    (if (in? 'the xs) #t #f)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `if` is incorrect; only the last `if` actually does anything. (To help prevent these kinds of errors, Racket bans the use of one-armed `if` expressions.) Perhaps you would like to use `cond` instead?

```
(define (det? xs)
  (cond ((in? 'a xs) #t)
        ((in? 'an xs) #t)
        ((in? 'the xs) #t)
        (else #f)))
```

This macro-expands to the following `if`s:

```
(if (in? 'a xs)
    #t
    (if (in? 'an xs)
        #t
        (if (in? 'the xs)
            #t
            #f)))
```

Notice how that's different from your series of `if` expressions.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing **(*1)** as an explicit return statement in Scheme; a procedure just returns the value of the last expression. [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311752/1193075) has shown you alternatives with `cond` and correct, 2-armed `if`s.

If you find yourself with conditionals returning `#t`  and `#f` there's usually a more elegant alternative using boolean logic, in this case:

```
(define det?
  (lambda (xs)
    (or (in? 'a xs) 
        (in? 'an xs) 
        (in? 'the xs))))
```

and `in?` could be expressed as

```
(define in? 
  (lambda (y xs)
    (and (memq y xs) #t)))
```

---

**(*1)** I was lying, of course. You *can* have this effet using [call/cc](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/callcc.html) or any variation thereof. It's an advanced subject and not appropriate for your situiation, but to give you a glimpse of what it would like:

```
(define det?
  (lambda (xs)
    (call/cc 
      (lambda (return)
        (when (in? 'a xs)   (return #t))
        (when (in? 'an xs)  (return #t))
        (when (in? 'the xs) (return #t))
        #f))))
```

Note that I use `when`, not `if`, since they are still one-armed conditions.